# MP3 widget Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this view where I have a list of calls and they all have a link to a recording. Once you click on a link it takes you to chrome built in mp3 player. Any way I can have a MP3 player widget and each time the link is clicked the call gets played on the widget?

Comment: What if I user Firefox, or Edge, or Opera, or Vivaldi, or Lynx?
You can offer a service/link but you can not choose how a user consumes that service.

Comment: It's an internal system for our company -- we require chrome usage.

Comment: Then use a group policy and force all mp3 links to open in a given app.

Comment: By widget, do you mean a box on the page with play/pause/stop buttons and a display of the current time? If so, that would be done in JavaScript and HTML – Rails has nothing built-in to help you with that use-case. You could use [howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/) to handle the loading, playing, and stopping of the sounds, and jQuery for the event handlers on the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `<audio>` tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) to play the file inline on the page.

If you need more control, customization, or cross-browser support, take a look at something like [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)